# Is there a way to merge a commit to a previous point on master in git?

Tags: git

Sorry if this is a very basic question, but my company recently switched to git and I'm trying to get up to speed. I'm having a hard time finding an answer with searches.

Here is the scenario:

You have a version 1 of your product on master. Later you release a version 2 and merge that release onto master. However, there is a bug reported in version 1, and some users don't want to switch to version 2. They just want to keep using version 1, but they want the bug fixed in a version 1.1.

Is there a way to checkout the version 1 checkpoint on master, do a bug fix, check that back into master, and then forward the fix up to version 2 on master? This would be useful for preserving history, rather than having to just create a separate version 1 branch hanging out there and cherry picking the fix onto master.

Edit: This has been tagged as a duplicate and I've been linked to a question about how to checkout previous commits. That is not my question. My question is how to do an emergency fix to a previous check in and then forward merge that into later check ins to preserve history.

Answer (score 3):

Take two: Applying a commit to an earlier state as well as master HEAD.

First, checkout the earlier state and create a branch.

```
git checkout <commit hash>
git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
```

OR checkout the original feature branch.

```
git checkout <merged-branch-name>
```

Then make your changes. Push up the branch and share it with your clients using that branch.

Now, cherry-pick your change commit onto master:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <commit hash>
```

As with any merge, this may result in conflicts. You'l need to deal with them as usual.

Comment: I know how to checkout previous commits. My question is if there's a way to checkin to those previous commits and have the changes forwarded to commits that happened later.

Comment: I suppose that mostly works. What I don't like about it is that I want master to be a complete history of all version releases, including hotfixes. However, we have a later version already merged into master, but need to hotfix a previous version. Your method works to get the intended code to the clients, but doesn't create a perfect history on the master branch itself. There will always be that other branch with the hotfix dangling out there in case there's another bug that also needs to be fixed in that version.

Comment: You cannot make `master` represent all the history of all the versions, when those versions change concurrently in time: for that you need separated branches. What we do in these cases is to fix the bug in master, and then cherry-pick that fix to the `release-1` branch. That way master is The Right History, while the `release-1` branches is the just version 1.0 plus cherry-picked bugfixes. We use `cherry-pick -x` to keep track of which fixes has been applied to which branches.

Comment: Basically, what I'm asking is if there's a way to insert a new commit between two previous commits on the same branch and merge it forward to all later commits.

Comment: @mrplainswalker: no. Commits are uniquely identified by their hash IDs and their hash IDs are computed from their contents, which include their history. If you did insert a commit, that would *change* the hash ID of all subsequent commits. You *can* do that (by copying every "downstream" commit to a new one), but it means that all *other* copies of the repository are now invalid. This is not a good development plan.

Comment: What you should do instead, ideally, is to make a *new* branch into which you incorporate the fix, then merge this new branch, one branch at a time, into each branch that needs the fix. See [Raymond Chen's ten-part series on this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325).